# Build dependencies for emacs24 could not be satisfied 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, emacs

I want to manually install **emacs24.4** and am following the widely available tutorials for doing so under **14.04** but when I want to install the required build-dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libwayland-dev (>= 1.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for emacs24 could not be satisfied.
```

How can I resolve this problem as trying to install the dependency manually gets me into an endless recursion on different unmet dependencies.

As requested by comments:

```
apt-cache policy libwayland-dev
libwayland-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.4.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.4.0-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

As requested by comments:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
$>
```

(emtpy output)

I did more digging and it seems that the libwayland-dev depends on too old versions:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwayland-dev : Depends: libwayland-client0 (= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libwayland-server0 (= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libwayland-cursor0 (= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
```

As when I try to install (all updates are installed):

```
sudo apt-get install libwayland-client0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libwayland-client0 is already the newest version.

dpkg -s libwayland-client0
Package: libwayland-client0
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 95
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: wayland
Version: 1.7.0-0ubuntu1~trusty1
```

A **DOWNGRADE** of the dependencies is **NO OPTION** as I have (of course) dependencies on the newer libs, though if it is possible to have two library versions installed at the same time, and this fixes the problem, i'll consider that a working solution.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libwayland-dev`

Comment: Try an explicit `sudo apt-get install libwayland-dev`

Comment: @A.B. _How can I resolve this problem as trying to install the dependency manually gets me into an endless recursion on different unmet dependencies._

Comment: [Edit] the question again and add the output of `apt-mark showhold`

Comment: The command `sudo apt-get update` works?

Comment: @A.B. Yes it does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* upgrade from Trusty to Vivid. But you use a LTS release, therefore, another possibility:

Change the dependencies with the steps below, but I can not guarantee that it is without side effects. On the other hand you do not have much choice if you do not want to downgrade the other packages.

But it's *only* a development library and therefore your system will not be otherwise affected.

Forcing installation via

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all libwayland-dev_1.4.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

would **NOT** work, after the next `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` or `sudo apt-get upgrade` you would have the problem

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwayland-dev : Depends: libwayland-client0 (= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.0-0ubuntu1 is installed
                  Depends: libwayland-server0 (= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.0-0ubuntu1 is installed
                  Depends: libwayland-cursor0 (= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.0-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

---

#### Therefore

1. Download the deb file `libwayland-dev_1.4.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

   ```
   cd; wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wayland/libwayland-dev_1.4.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Change the dependencies

   ```
   mkdir deb$$
   cp libwayland-dev_1.4.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb deb$$
   cd deb$$
   dpkg-deb -x libwayland-dev_1.4.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb deb
   cd deb
   dpkg-deb -e ../libwayland-dev_1.4.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   perl -i -pe 's/= 1\.4\.0-1ubuntu1/>= 1.4.0-1ubuntu1/g' DEBIAN/control
   ```
3. Recreate the deb file

   ```
   cd ..
   sudo dpkg-deb -b deb
   ```
4. Install the deb file

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i deb.deb
   ```

---

Here is the installation on my Vivid

```
% apt-cache policy libwayland-client0
libwayland-client0:
  Installed: 1.7.0-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.7.0-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.7.0-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.7.0-0ubuntu1~vivid1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages

% apt-cache policy libwayland-dev
libwayland-dev:
  Installed: 1.4.0-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.7.0-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1.7.0-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
     1.7.0-0ubuntu1~vivid1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.4.0-1ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: do I understand correctly that you 'just' change the dependency string in the deb package? This will definitly work, but aren't dependencies there for a reason?

Comment: I edited the comment

Comment: Sure have a reason. But your decision (no downgrade) leaves very little space.

Comment: yes you are right, and I'll accept your answer if no better solution pops up, but I am quite wary about the idea of manipulating dependency files as I am afraid that it'll haunt me at some other time.

Comment: It's only a development library and therefore your system will not be otherwise affected.

Comment: Wow! I'd never have thought of that!  @Sim: 25000 rep user, 7 gold medals, 24 silver medals.  I don't think *anyone* else will come up with *any* other answer...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby though not strictly an answer to the question (as I mention 14.04). **Up**grading the distro also solves the problem.

Comment: You use a LTS release. Why should I recommend to upgrade?

Comment: @A.B. It is a working solution.  No need to argue here your solution is great. It was just a side node which might be interesting for future visitors as it is possible to do an upgrade from lts to normal.

Comment: ok, all clear =)