# dependency problems prevent configuration of energytycoon

Tags: package-management, 15.04, deb

On a virtual ubuntu box (15.04) I am trying to install a debian package using the following command

```
sudo dpkg -i energytycoon_release1_package.deb
```

which results in some errors:

```
Selecting previously unselected package energytycoon.
(Reading database ... 271927 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack energytycoon_release1_package.deb ...
Unpacking energytycoon (1.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of energytycoon:
 energytycoon depends on libogremain-1.6.4.
 energytycoon depends on libois-1.2.0.

dpkg: error processing package energytycoon (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 energytycoon
```

When I try to install one of the missing package, I get the following output:

```
> sudo apt-get install libois-1.2.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libois-1.2.0:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libois-1.2.0:i386' has no installation candidate
```

Or for the other package:

```
> sudo apt-get install libogremain-1.6.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libogremain-1.6.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libogremain-1.6.4'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You could change the dependencies of this package. Similarly, as described herein: http://askubuntu.com/a/664262/367165

Answer (score 0):

libois-1.2.0 is an obsolete package and has been replaced in recent versions of Ubuntu by [libois-1.3.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/libois-1.3.0).

If you need the old version you can still try to install it using `sudo dpkg -i <deb_file>`.

The deb package can still be downloaded from launchpad: [amd64](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/48485574/libois-1.2.0_1.2.0-2_amd64.deb) or [i386](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/48289226/libois-1.2.0_1.2.0-2_i386.deb).

Example for amd64: `sudo dpkg -i libois-1.2.0_1.2.0-2_amd64.deb`

Comment: @Alex: And did you try to download the amd64 package and install it with dpkg?

Comment: @Alex what's the result of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Ok, this package seems to be installed. Now I need to install the other package (libogremain-1.6.4). See my updated question. But still, trying the package I am trying to install in the first place gives the exact same error, as if libois-1.2.0 is not installed at all!

Comment: Try to install the i386 version instead for  libois-1.2.0

Comment: Then I get a whole bunch of new errors: `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libois-1.2.0:
 libois-1.2.0 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 libois-1.2.0 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
 libois-1.2.0 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1).
 libois-1.2.0 depends on libx11-6 (>= 0).`

Comment: @The game you're trying to install requires very very old packages that will bring a lot of broken dependencies (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ogre/1.6.4.dfsg1-1). Unfortunately I don't think you can easily work around the problem.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help anyway. I guess I will give up, as I do in most cases when I am trying to install something. Well, I guess I need to develop my own game then...